# <!--[if IE]> not working in any browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, if-statement

Hi I am having a very strange issue and have searched Google for answers without success!

I only want the body background colour to change to red when in IE however it doesn't work.

I have the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {background-color:red;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>TEST</body>

</html>
```

I am testing in IE 11, and latest versions of Chrome and FF

Any ideas?

Comment: @DK64 it's a conditional comment for IE

Comment: You have to remove them @Harvey since they are not supported

Comment: also you forgot the `--` before `[endif]`

Comment: @user689 that's the correct syntax for an if the -- would only be added if it were and if not

Answer (score 8):

Conditional comments are unsupported in IE 10 and IE 11, since those browsers are fairly compatible (by IE standards, anyway), with HTML5. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details

Answer (score 2):

Conditional comments were only supported from IE 5 up until IE 9.
See the link: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html